# How to fix SqlConnectionString.Open() exception, login failed

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I'm trying to establish a SqlConnection in my C# application, the application was working fine with Oracle DB but I wish to connect it to MS SQL now. I've made the necessary code changes which are mentioned in the code section below. The issue is `SqlConnectionString,Open()` throws `exception`

In web.config file I've added the CONNECTIONSTRING value as `"Server=TCP:myServerName,Port_No\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=Username;Password=Password;"`

```
private DataSet FireQuery(SqlCommand command, String tablename)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        conn.Open();    //Code throws exception here

        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Connection = conn;

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, tablename);
        conn.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

Exception thrown is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`:

> Cannot open database "mydataBase" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'Username'.

Comment: most probably your password is wrong

Comment: @It'satrap Credentials are correct, I've also tested the connection with datalink provider dialog, connection gets established with my credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "cannot open database" error means the authentication succeeded but the database context could not be set. This indicates either database "myDataBase" does not exist on the instance (or is offline) or the user does not have permissions to use it. In the latter case, the script example below will allow the user to use the database and objects.

```
USE mydataBase;
--create a database user mapped to login of same name
CREATE USER Username; 
--also GRANT permissions on objects used directly by application
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE dbo.YourTable TO Username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection string in the config file (or wherever you are getting it and passing to "FireQuery". The Username or password is wrong.
Error is telling you that the username you are passing is "Username". Literally.

Are you sure it even exists an user with such a stupid username? (easy findable and bruteforceable)

Usually sql server connects with user "sa" or something like that, unless you create specific users on your own. I think you or someone else just copy pasted a connection string found in some online guide and didn't bothered to change username or password.

Comment: Credentials are correct, I've also tested the connection with datalink provider dialog, connection gets established with my credentials and btw 'username' is just a random word I chose to post it here not in my code.

Comment: @m_alpha Does your connection string respects any of these standards?
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax